# npm install ZeroRPC error

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, zerorpc

I cannot install the ["ZeroRPC"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zerorpc) package.

```
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.14.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
```

I followed [the Robert Kehoe tutorial](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/) without success.

---

Messages :

```
  gyp ERR! build error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
  gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\*******\GoogleDrive\******\Sources\*********\app\node_modules\zmq
  gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
  gyp ERR! not ok
  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "zmq"
  npm ERR! node v4.2.2
  npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

  npm ERR! zmq@2.14.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.14.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
  npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
  npm ERR! You can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

---

- Node -v = v4.2.2
- npm -v = 2.14.7